# A problem on non-measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

If $G$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ with $m_*(G) > 0$ I have to prove that a subset of $G$ is non-measurable. I know the proof when $G=[0,1]$ and $G=\Bbb R$. Very little hint enough.

Comment: $0<m_{\star}(G) \le m^{\star}(G) $.Any set with positive outer measure contains a non measurable set